# The name 'string' does not exist in the current context error c#

Tags: c#

Here is the code I am currently having the issue with:

```
        try

        {
            int realopid = Convert.ToInt16(operatorid);
        }
        catch (OverflowException)
        {
            //Create Message Box
            MessageBox.Show("Please Scan Valid Operator ID", "Operator ID");
            operatorid = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Scan Operator ID", "Operator ID");
        }

            string res = lookupName( realopid );
```

Comment: lookup(realopid) is what doesn't exist.

Comment: May you please provide what does `lookupName` do? Also, may you please provide what is exactly `**realopid**`? :)

Comment: Post entire method code, it is not enough to understand the context.

Comment: lookupName is whats being used to go out to a server we have to find names. realopid is my string converted to int. The Answer below worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are defining the `realopid` inside the try block. it is only visible there. You should define it outside.

```
int realopid = 0;
try
{
   realopid = Convert.ToInt16(operatorid);
}
catch (OverflowException)
{
    //Create Message Box
    MessageBox.Show("Please Scan Valid Operator ID", "Operator ID");
    operatorid = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Scan Operator ID", "Operator ID");
 }
string res = lookupName(realopid);
```